# How can I combine each string together from two or more lists of strings?

Tags: c#, linq

What I am trying to do is say I have a List of Lists of string where the lists are...

```
list1 = "A", "B", "C"
list2 = "1", "2", "3"
list3 = "Dog"
...
```

then I get a list with

```
  newList = "A1Dog", "A2Dog", "A3Dog", "B1Dog", "B2Dog", "B3Dog", "C1Dog", 
  "C2Dog", "C3Dog"
```

Is there a way to do this with LINQ or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried anything? This seems like homework which you're just dumping on us hoping we'll do it for you.

Comment: This isn't a "write my code for me" service where you give us a list of requirements and we turn them into working code. Show us some code and what you've tried and we can help you fix it. Create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For example, instead of giving us pseudo code of your "list of lists", spend the 30 seconds creating an actual c# list of lists so we can copy it into our IDE to help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can simply use multiple `from` clauses:

```
var result =
    from x in list1
    from y in list2
    from z in list3
    select x+y+z;
```

In the `csharp` interactive shell, this gives:

```
csharp> var list1 = new string[] {"A", "B", "C"};
csharp> var list2 = new string[] {"1", "2", "3"}; 
csharp> var list3 = new string[] {"Dog"};         
csharp>     var result =
      >         from x in list1
      >         from y in list2
      >         from z in list3
      >         select x+y+z;
csharp> result
{ "A1Dog", "A2Dog", "A3Dog", "B1Dog", "B2Dog", "B3Dog", "C1Dog", "C2Dog", "C3Dog" }
```

Comment: I guess this *is* a "do my homework for me" site after all...

Comment: @tnw - If the question were a homework problem, I'd be surprised if using Linq to solve it would be acceptable (it might be).  Usually those types of assignments ask the student to use `for` loops or something similar.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Ok, lets assume that this is not homework for a moment then. It's still a zero-effort "do my work for me" question.